# Optimized SQL query for getting last modified date of a user information

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to display the last modified date/time of all users. 
The user information is spread out in multiple tables (all of them containing a last_modified_date column).
The tables are as follows.
User_Details,
User_Contact_Details,
User_Social_Media_Details.

My first thought was to perform a UNION ALL as follows.

```
select user.id, user.last_modified_date from 
(
(select id, last_modified_date from "User_Details" order by id)
UNION ALL
(select user_id as id, last_modified_date from "User_Contact_Details" order by id)
UNION ALL
(select user_id as id, last_modified_date from "User_Social_Media_Details" order by id)
) as user 
where user.last_modified_date is not null
order by user.id, user.last_modified_date desc
```

This will get me all the users and their last modified date sorted in descending and then perform a Top 1 for each users.
Which has left me wondering if this is the right and optimized approach.

Any help/advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I am using this in PostgreSQL, but SQL server is also fine for me to understand. That is why I didn't specify the DBMS product.

Comment: do you need just last user or each user last modified date

Comment: I need last modified date of each users. It is for a report generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want the latest modification date for each user. Which boils down to a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem (with n=1). And they are typically solved using `distinct on ()` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on (usr.id) id, last_modified_date 
from 
(
  select id, last_modified_date 
  from "User_Details" 

  UNION ALL

  select user_id as id, last_modified_date 
  from "User_Contact_Details" 

  UNION ALL

  select user_id as id, last_modified_date 
  from "User_Social_Media_Details" 
) as usr 
where last_modified_date is not null
order by id, last_modified_date desc;
```

The `order by` inside the union queries is not really necessary, unless you want to pre-filter the user IDs in there already, which might be more efficient:

```
select distinct on (usr.id) id, last_modified_date 
from 
(
  select distinct on (id) id, last_modified_date 
  from "User_Details" 
  order by id, last_modified_date desc

  UNION ALL

  select distinct on (user_id) user_id as id, last_modified_date 
  from "User_Contact_Details" 
  order by user_id, last_modified_date desc

  UNION ALL

  select distinct on (user_id) user_id as id, last_modified_date 
  from "User_Social_Media_Details" 
  order by user_id, last_modified_date desc

) as usr 
where last_modified_date is not null
order by id, last_modified_date desc;
```

You still need the `distinct on ()` in the outer query because the same user ID could be returned from the different branches of the UNION.

---

`user` is a reserved keyword, avoid using it as an identifier. And if you do, you have to quote it `"user"` to avoid confusion with the built-in function `user`

---

If the `"User_Details"` table is the "master" table, referenced by the others and you just want to get the latest modification date per user id, regardless in which table that occurred, you could also use a join with a group by:

```
select id, 
       max(greatest(ud.last_modified_date, ucd.last_modified_date, usmd.last_modified_date)) as latest_modification
from "User_Details" ud
  left join "User_Contact_Details" ucd on ucd.user_ud = ud.id
  left join "User_Social_Media_Details"  usmd on usmd.user_id = ud.id
group by id;
```

Comment: I am still wondering if UNION ALL is the right and optimal solution.

Comment: @gzone: I don't see a different way of doing that if the user information is spread across multiple tables. The question is: why don't you have a **single** user account table that is referenced through a foreign key from the other tables.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name: The "user_id" column is the foreign key reference to "id" column of "User_Details" table. We still need to maintain multiple tables, because there are different activities that relates to user that needs to be recorded in individual tables.

Comment: @gzone: can you have multiple rows in the "details" tables for each user?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name: Nope. There will be only 1 row per user. But, there can be multiple rows for a particular user in "User_Contact_Details" and "User_Social_Media_Details". So, I just need to get only the last_modified_date of the entire user info. That is by combining "User_Details", "User_Contact_Details" and "User_Social_Media_Details" and there is a couple more tables that holds records of user activities.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks, man. I have a feeling that the LEFT JOIN will be better than the UNION ALL. What do you think ?

Comment: @gzone: check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 0):

Run on each table independently:

```
select u.id, u.last_modified_date 
from ((select id, last_modified_date 
       from "User_Details" 
       order by last_modified_date desc
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select user_id, last_modified_date
       from "User_Contact_Details" 
       order by last_modified_date desc
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select user_id, last_modified_date
       from "User_Media_Details" 
       order by last_modified_date desc
       limit 1
      ) 
     ) u 
order by last_modified_date desc
limit 1;
```

By running the `limit` in the subqueries, the database engine only returns one row and can use an index.

EDIT:

If you need this for *each* user rather than all, then use `group by` in the subqueries and outer query:

```
select u.id, max(u.last_modified_date) 
from ((select id, max(last_modified_date) as last_modified_date
       from "User_Details" 
       group by id
      ) union all
      (select user_id, max(last_modified_date) as last_modified_date
       from "User_Contact_Details" 
       group by user_id
      ) union all
      (select user_id, max(last_modified_date) as last_modified_date
       from "User_Media_Details" 
       group by user_id
      ) 
     ) u 
group by user_id;
```